# Foreach Multiple Dimension Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following output created from a PHP script I have created:

```
Array
(
[cage] =>  OK
[logicaldrive] => Array
    (
        [logicaldrive 1] => Array
            (
                [size] => 2.7 TB
                [raid] => RAID 1
                [status] => OK
            )
    )

[physicaldrive] => Array
    (
        [logicaldrive 1] => Array
            (
                [physicaldrive 2I:1:1] => Array
                    (
                        [bay] => port 2I:box 1:bay 1
                        [type] => SATA
                        [size] => 3 TB
                        [status] => OK
                    )

                [physicaldrive 2I:1:2] => Array
                    (
                        [bay] => port 2I:box 1:bay 2
                        [type] => SATA
                        [size] => 3 TB
                        [status] => OK
                    )
            )

    )
```

I would like to be able to format this data into a table, I have tried but unable to run a foreach loop on sections of the array, for example if I want a table to have the information from:

```
[logicaldrive] => Array
    (
        [logicaldrive 1] => Array
            (
                [size] => 2.7 TB
                [raid] => RAID 1
                [status] => OK
            )

    )
```

I can't work out how to get the values of size, raid, status without knowing the key (logicaldrive 1) which depending on the system that the code has run on will be different each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$all_data; //your complete array

foreach($all_data as $key=>$sub_array){
   if($key === "logicaldrive"){
       foreach($sub_array as $key=>$sub_sub_array){
           echo $key;//logicaldrive 1
           foreach($sub_sub_array as $key=>$fact){
               echo '<td>'.$key.'='.$fact.'<td>';//size=2.7 TB,raid=RAID 1, status=OK
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Obviously you will need to wrap the `td` elements appropriately this is just an example to get you going with the logic

Comment: That works perfectly, however for some reason it does add extra bank <td></td> between each result in the foreach statement.

Comment: I guess that is in the second sub array with the 'physicaldrive' keys right?

Comment: In each level of the looping do a `print_r($array)` so you can see the structure of each sub array. This will make it easier to visualise what is going on and you should spot where the blank is happening